# Может ли mod_rewrite упасть отдельно от апач?

Tags: apache, mod_rewrite

Простите за нубский вопрос но всё же, имею строку в .htaccess

```
<Files private.xml>
deny from all
</Files>
```

есть ли вероятность что из **ВНЕ** кто-то получит к этому файлу доступ?

Answer (score 2):

Не храните файлы к которым не нужен прямой доступ вебсервера в папке куда смотрит вебсервер :) ПХП работает с файловой системой, поэтому файл может лежать где угодно

Answer (score 0):

установи права доступа на файл через chmod на 644 и тогда точно ни кто не получит доступ к нему.

Comment: Спасибо, но PHP внутри сервака сможет с ним работать?

Comment: не правильный совет :)

Comment: В общем инструкция в сабж запретит доступ к файлу из сети интернет, но можно обойтись и chmod 644

Comment: вообщето пхп работает из под пользователя апача, поэтому если у апача не будет прав на чтение, то не будет прав и у пхп, следовательно -- зачем этот файл вообще сюда класть? :) rm -f private.xml тогда уж...